# How I get the Values of a Lookup field in Silverlight with Client OM

Tags: c#, sharepoint

First of all, an apology for my poor English. Ok.

I have in Sharepoint 2010 a list with a Lookup Field (List1), and other list (List2) with the values of the Lookup field of the First list. In my Silverlight Application, I'm working with Client Object Model. I have a ComboBox (Lookup field of the List1) that I want to fill with the values of the List2.

When I select an item of the comboBox i want to save that value in the Lookup field of my List1. I tried with FieldLookup and FieldLookupValue Class but don't have any successful result.

Any idea to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
IEnumerableMyStackPanelToBindOnSearch = IEnumerableMyStackPanelList.Where(StackPanel => (((FieldLookupValue)StackPanel["StackPanelLookUp"]).LookupValue.ToLowerInvariant() == forPanel.Title.ToLowerInvariant()));
```